# How can I solve the forever loading issue of Odoo?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-14

My Odoo Database has a size of 75000+ products in product.template table.

Whenever I try to type a value in product.template many2one, application just goes into forever loading mode.

I have re-configured the server memory & RAM resources and also tried with odoo.conf file to get to a solution.

But, so far none of them seems to be working.

Anyone can guide me towards the right way?

Comment: Have you made customization on products or is it Odoo vanilla code?

Comment: Customizations include custom fields, apart from those, there are no major customizations @CZoellner

Comment: not a solution, but will make It workable. Use `web_m2x_options` and set drop-down options to 0 so searching a product will only be possible by searching more option 
the good thing about that is that the product will be searched only when press enter

Comment: @Shravy even minor changes can lead to bad performance. Could you add those changes as list of key points to your question, like "added 2 many2one fields" or "changed write method"? But have in mind, could be very difficult to find the reason of that performance problem.